# Hashtags in newsfeed not working for certain users

Tags: sharepoint-online, newsfeed, hashtags

Normally, when you hover over a hashtag in a Newsfeed, that hashtag changes color to show you that its a clickable link that will lead you to relevant conversations where that tag has been mentioned.

However, we are experiencing a problem where certain users with access to a site where a Newsfeed has been setup are not able to use the hashtags as clickable links, but are able to make posts, etc.  I have checked these users' permissions and they are the same as people who are able to use the hashtags, I have even created a separate site with another newsfeed and they weren't able to use the hashtags on that site either.  What could be the problem?

Sharepoint version is sharepoint online 2013.

Comment: Is it possible that the web browser is affecting their experience?

Comment: No, they got the same result in chrome, firefox, and IE.  Also, I used a browser on their PC to login myself and was able to see and use the hashtag links fine.

Comment: We have the same issue - did anybody resolve it?